# c# System.InvalidOperationException: This OracleTransaction has completed; it is no longer usable

Tags: c#, oracle

i have the following error:

```
   System.InvalidOperationException: This OracleTransaction has completed; it is no longer usable
```

trying to make an insert into the db

here is the code:

```
    OracleTransaction myTrans = null;   
    OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("INSERT INTO ZTMP_SAM_TB_ELAB_PDR " + 
    "  VALUES (:1,:2,:3,:4,:5,:6,:7,:8,:9,:10,:11,:12,:13,:14)", connection);
    myTrans = connection.BeginTransaction();
    cmd.Transaction = myTrans; 
    /*
    ( :facilityid,:taxid,
    :plantcode,:capdr,:fullmetkeym2,
    :corrmetidm2,:stopreadingm2,
    :corrstopreadm2,:fullmetkeym1,
    :corrmetidm1,:stopreadingm1,:corrstopreadm1,
    :stopreadtimem2,:stopreadtimem1)
    */

    file = new System.IO.StreamReader(path+FileUpload1.FileName);
    while((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
       string[] split = line.Split(',');


       cmd.Parameters.Add("1", OracleType.VarChar, 64).Value = split[0];
       cmd.Parameters.Add("2", OracleType.VarChar, 64).Value = "";
       cmd.Parameters.Add("3", OracleType.VarChar, 64).Value = "";
       cmd.Parameters.Add("4", OracleType.Number).Value = Convert.ToInt32(split[1]);
       cmd.Parameters.Add("5", OracleType.VarChar, 64).Value = split[6];
       cmd.Parameters.Add("6", OracleType.VarChar, 64).Value = split[7];
       cmd.Parameters.Add("7", OracleType.Number).Value = Convert.ToInt32(split[8]);
       cmd.Parameters.Add("8", OracleType.Number).Value = Convert.ToInt32(split[9]);
       cmd.Parameters.Add("9", OracleType.VarChar, 80).Value = split[2];
       cmd.Parameters.Add("10", OracleType.VarChar, 80).Value = split[3];
       cmd.Parameters.Add("11", OracleType.Number).Value = Convert.ToInt32(split[4]);
       cmd.Parameters.Add("12", OracleType.Number).Value = Convert.ToInt32(split[5]);
       DateTime date1,date2;

       DateTime.TryParseExact(split[10], "dd/MM/yyyy", null, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out date1);
       DateTime.TryParseExact(split[11], "dd/MM/yyyy", null, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out date2);

       cmd.Parameters.Add("13", OracleType.DateTime).Value = date1;
       cmd.Parameters.Add("14", OracleType.DateTime).Value = date2;
      try
        {
           cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

           myTrans.Commit();    
        }   
       catch(Exception ex){

        myTrans.Rollback(); 
        Label1.Text = ex.Message;
        //"Si e' verificato un errore nell'inserimento dei dati nella tabella ZTMP_SAM_TB_ELAB_PDR";
        }
       /*Per ogni elemento esegui l'insert*/
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your while loop commits the transaction several times, assuming you want to commit all the inserted rows

```
// ...
file = new System.IO.StreamReader(path+FileUpload1.FileName);
try
{
  while((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
  {
    // Parameters...
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
  }

  myTrans.Commit();     
}                   
catch(Exception ex)
{
  myTrans.Rollback(); 
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
bool flag=true;
OracleTransaction myTrans = null;   
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("INSERT INTO ZTMP_SAM_TB_ELAB_PDR " + 
"  VALUES (:1,:2,:3,:4,:5,:6,:7,:8,:9,:10,:11,:12,:13,:14)", connection);
connection.open();//if not done already.
myTrans = connection.BeginTransaction();
cmd.Transaction = myTrans; 

file = new System.IO.StreamReader(path+FileUpload1.FileName);
while((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
   string[] split = line.Split(',');


   cmd.Parameters.Add("1", OracleType.VarChar, 64).Value = split[0];
   cmd.Parameters.Add("2", OracleType.VarChar, 64).Value = "";
   cmd.Parameters.Add("3", OracleType.VarChar, 64).Value = "";
   cmd.Parameters.Add("4", OracleType.Number).Value = Convert.ToInt32(split[1]);
   cmd.Parameters.Add("5", OracleType.VarChar, 64).Value = split[6];
   cmd.Parameters.Add("6", OracleType.VarChar, 64).Value = split[7];
   cmd.Parameters.Add("7", OracleType.Number).Value = Convert.ToInt32(split[8]);
   cmd.Parameters.Add("8", OracleType.Number).Value = Convert.ToInt32(split[9]);
   cmd.Parameters.Add("9", OracleType.VarChar, 80).Value = split[2];
   cmd.Parameters.Add("10", OracleType.VarChar, 80).Value = split[3];
   cmd.Parameters.Add("11", OracleType.Number).Value = Convert.ToInt32(split[4]);
   cmd.Parameters.Add("12", OracleType.Number).Value = Convert.ToInt32(split[5]);
   DateTime date1,date2;

   DateTime.TryParseExact(split[10], "dd/MM/yyyy", null, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out date1);
   DateTime.TryParseExact(split[11], "dd/MM/yyyy", null, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out date2);

   cmd.Parameters.Add("13", OracleType.DateTime).Value = date1;
   cmd.Parameters.Add("14", OracleType.DateTime).Value = date2;
  try
    {
       cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();          
    }   
   catch(Exception ex)
    {
      myTrans.Rollback(); 
      Label1.Text = ex.Message;  
      flag=false; 
      break; 
    }

}
if(flag)
  myTrans.Commit(); 
connection.close();
```

You are committing the transaction inside while loop, that is why after first iteration, the transaction is committing twice that is why you are getting the exception.

Instead, commit the transaction after the while loop completes, as shown in above code.

Comment: In case of exception this code will execute both a rollback and a commit

Comment: Sorry, That is a mistake, updating the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You call a commit for each loop. This will fail on the second loop. You can move the commit out of the loop or just use the [TransactionScope class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx)

```
using(TransactionScope ts = new TransactionScope())
using(OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(cnstring))
{
    bool errorFound = false;
    OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("INSERT INTO ZTMP_SAM_TB_ELAB_PDR " + 
                "  VALUES (:1,:2,:3,:4,:5,:6,:7,:8,:9,:10,:11,:12,:13,:14)", connection);
    ....
    file = new System.IO.StreamReader(path+FileUpload1.FileName);
    while((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
       ....
       try
       {
           cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
       }   
       catch(Exception ex)
       {
          Label1.Text = ex.Message;
          errorFound = true;
          break; 
       }
    }
    if(!errorFound) ts.Complete();

}
```

Exiting from the using block whitout calling complete will automatically Rollback your inserts

Comment: i can not use this because i m using .net 3.5 :(((

Comment: Why not? It is available since Framework 2.0. Something related to Oracle?

Comment: sorry for the lag . i was trying with  System.Transactions.TransactionScope  but i need to add the dll to the project and i dont know how because i m not using Visual studio but normal notepad :(